# Drupal 7 on hosted IIS 7

Tags: php, asp.net, iis, drupal, drupal-7

I have a annoying problem with my hosted domain on iis. I installed a drupal 7 instance in a subdirectory of my webspace.
When i access mydomain.com/drupal I get an 500 Internal Server Error: "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." nothing more, nothing less.
When i access mydomain.com/drupal/index.php the site works fine except the /drupal?q= syntax which is not rewritten properly (index.php?q= works fine).

I hoped if i transfer my installation to my wwwroot the problem would vanish but instead less works. Now I can't even access mydomain.com/drupal/index.php (resulting in 500 aswell).

Since the iis is hosted by my internet provider i can't configure the Settings nor can I access server logs.

I tried playing with web.config including httpErros errorMode=Detailed" passthrough and other stuff but all I get is that damn 500 Internal Server Error with NO Information.

If the web.config is invalid xml syntax I get a proper Error page reporting that the syntax is incorrect, so it seems the web.config is parsed but somehow ignored.

Do you have any ideas that could help my case?

Thanks

Edit: I forgot to mention i tried setting access rights to execute as well as read and write for web.config and index.php but didn't change a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the web.config shipping with Drupal 7 caused the problems. 
I found this article and used the proposed web.config as stated there and now the homepage works fine.

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/install-drupal-on-iis

Comment: And there was obviously a problem in the ISP's server Configuration. They fixed it somehow.